# Comparator - Special Character sorting

Tags: java, collections

I want to sort names alphabetically , but special characters should come first not last.

From Below code special characters coming last,

```
Collections.sort(elementList,new Comparator<Element>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Element o1, Element o2) {
                    return o1.getDisplayName().toUpperCase().compareTo(o2.getDisplayName().toUpperCase());
                }
            });
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: If default order of string does not help, You would need to write your own logic to treat objects with special character in a different manner.

Comment: Could you please provide few examples how do you expect the names to be sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by special characters? Do you mean punctuation characters? They are already sorted before alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 0):

The below program works. It sorts the Strings with special characters at the start.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ComparatorDemo {
    String element;

    public ComparatorDemo(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ComparatorDemo> stringCollection = new LinkedList<>();
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("abcd"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("jklm"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("opr"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("zabh"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("bhuy"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("@theh#saj"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("*&^%$"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("**"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("!@#"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("@@#$"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("#$%$"));
        stringCollection.add(new ComparatorDemo("%^return"));
        System.out.println(stringCollection);
        Comparator<ComparatorDemo> comparator = new Comparator<ComparatorDemo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ComparatorDemo o1, ComparatorDemo o2) {
                return o1.element.toUpperCase().compareTo(
                        o2.element.toUpperCase());
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(stringCollection, comparator);
        System.out.println(stringCollection);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ComparatorDemo [element=" + element + "]";
    }

}

Output :
Unsorted List - [ComparatorDemo [element=abcd], ComparatorDemo [element=jklm], ComparatorDemo [element=opr], ComparatorDemo [element=zabh], ComparatorDemo [element=bhuy], ComparatorDemo [element=@theh#saj], ComparatorDemo [element=*&^%$], ComparatorDemo [element=**], ComparatorDemo [element=!@#], ComparatorDemo [element=@@#$], ComparatorDemo [element=#$%$], ComparatorDemo [element=%^return]]

Sorted List - [ComparatorDemo [element=!@#], ComparatorDemo [element=#$%$], ComparatorDemo [element=%^return], ComparatorDemo [element=*&^%$], ComparatorDemo [element=**], ComparatorDemo [element=@@#$], ComparatorDemo [element=@theh#saj], ComparatorDemo [element=abcd], ComparatorDemo [element=bhuy], ComparatorDemo [element=jklm], ComparatorDemo [element=opr], ComparatorDemo [element=zabh]]
```